# Sum values of certain field in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, categories

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a number of worksheets within it. One of the columns on each worksheet is called 'type'. This column is made of free text (a bit like a category).

What I'd like to do is on a separate worksheet, be able to collate all the different entries in 'type', and to be able to sum the corresponding values of them.

How is this possible?

Comment: This site is about programming, your question isn't.

Comment: Collate your sheets into a single table and create a pivot table from that data.

Comment: but a pivot table would require me to 'pivot' the data around? i want a list output of the entries in 'type' column and with their respective summed values over all the worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

On your separate worksheet you'll need to have the list of each of the different "types"

Using the `SumIf` function you can sum all the values that fit the criteria.  For instance if Sheet1 looks like this:

```
A       B
Type    Count
Big     2
Small   3
Round   4
Small   1
Big     7
Round   4
```

Then on Sheet2 you would have

```
A       B
Type    Total
Big     9
Small   4
Round   8
```

The formula in Column B on Sheet2 would look like:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A7,B2,Sheet1!B2:B7)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How I achieved this for my own particular use was to use this link (which I found via another StackOverflow answer) http://superuser.com/questions/189737/dynamically-updating-list-of-unique-column-entries-in-excel    This helped me set up the dynamic list of sorted, unique entries. I did try to implement the 'noblanks' list but as I have an indefinite amount of lines it took to long. So I decided to use an auto-filter to remove blank lines and that did the job for me. Hope it helps someone else,